# Powermockito/Java - Spying class under test to verify private method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, stubbing

I'm writing unit tests in java using Mockito/PowerMockito, but on the test I'm working on, I can't get rid of this UnfinishedStubbingException.

The method I'm trying to test is private, so I use WhiteBoxImpl to invoke the method.  Inside the method I invoke, a call is potentially made to another private method (call it pm2) in the class under test.  I want to verify that pm2 is never called, so I make a spy for the class under test, and verify pm2 is never() called.

So far, this test has always thrown an UnfinishedStubbingException, but I can't figure out what part of my test Powermockito doesn't like.  I have another (working) test that operates very similarly, except I don't need to verify the behavior of a method like pm2.  So in this working case, I don't need to create a spy for the class under test.  I believe my issue is somehow related to the spy, but I don't know of a way to test what I'm trying to test without it.

Here's what I have right now:

```
@Mock(name = "BO")
BO BOMock;
@Mock(name = "DAO")
DAOI DAOMock;

@InjectMocks
ServiceImpl service;

@Test
public void unitTest(){
    MessageObject msg = new MessageObject();
    Record recordMock = mock(Record.class);
    MetaData metaDataMock = mock(MetaData.class);

    doNothing().when(DAOMock).doAction(any(Param1.class), anyInt());
    when(DAOMock.doOtherAction(any(Param1.class), eq(msg.getId()))).thenReturn(recordMock);
    when(BOMock.getMetaData(anyInt(), anyInt()).thenReturn(metaDataMock);

    ServiceImpl spy = PowerMockito.spy(this.service);
    PowerMockito.doReturn(new Long(10)).when(spy, "checkDelay", recordMock, msg, metaDataMock);

    Whitebox.invokeMethod(spy, "process", msg);
    verify(recordMock, never()).getStatus();
}
```

Here's the method in the class ServiceImpl that I'm testing:

```
private BO BO = new BO();
private DAOI DAO = new DAO();

private void process(Message msg) {
    try {
        DAO.doAction(new Param1.class, msg.getId());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("some message");
        return;
    }

    Record record = null;

    try {

        int intParam1 = msg.getId();
        int intParam2 = msg.getDifferentId();

        MetaData metaData = BO.getMetaData(intParam1, intParam2);

        record = DAO.loadRecord(new Param1(), msg.getId());

        // checkDelay is a private method in ServiceImpl.java
        long delayForMinutes = checkDelay(record, msg, metaData);
        if(delayForMinutes > 0) {
            // Control should reach here
            logger.debug("some message");
            return;
        }

        // Control should not reach here

        if(Record != null && Record.getStatus() != CREATED) {
            logger.debug("some message");
            return;
        }

        // Perform various actions

    } catch(Exception e) {
        // Perform other various actions
    }
}
```

When I run this test I get an UnfinishedStubbingException.  The line at the top of the stack trace is:

```
DAO.doAction(new Param1.class, msg.getId());
```

The error message provides the following hints:

```
E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

But I can't seem to figure out how any of them apply to my situation.  Does anyone know what's going on behind the scenes to cause this error?

Thank you

Comment: UnitTests should not test implementation details. Therefore your test should not need to know that there are any non public methods in your class. You should inject an Instance of the DAO to your service class and mock that for the test (not using PowerMock...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem line is

```
when(DAOMock.doOtherAction(any(Param1.class), eq(msg.getId()))).loadRecord(recordMock);
```

You don't seem to have a `then`, `thenReturn` or `thenThrow` here.  You always need to use one of those with `when`.

Comment: I double checked my code, I transcribed that line wrong.  It should be ".thenReturn(recordMock)", not ".loadRecord(recordMock)".